# How do I use IKVM.NET to translate .JAR files into .dll files?

Tags: java, c#, dll, ikvm

I am building a C# project, which needs to execute java code. Nearly every suggested solution refers to a converter called [IKVM](https://github.com/windward-studios/ikvm8). Apparently this converter is able to translate the .JAR files into .DLL files.

I've tried to understand the documentation, but couldn't figure out how to use the converter. I've also installed the NuGet package for IKVM. However, that didn't make me any smarter either

How do I properly install, setup and use IKVM.NET in order to translate .JAR files into .DLL files?

I highly appreciate any suggestion or solution, sheers!

---

**1. Edit**

I've followed this [installation guide](https://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/wiki/Installation/) and somehow created a .dll by using the following command.

```
ikvmc FILENAME.jar -target:library
```

Nevertheless, I've got many errors while building the .dll

---

**2. Edit - Solution**

There are no errors with uncomplicated JAR files and I can use them as a DLL without any problems. Apparently not all Java components used in my JAR files can be translated or found in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things have changed quite a bit since this question was asked. Please read https://github.com/ikvm-revived/ikvm/blob/main/README.md

Since then we have released version 8.2.1, which has support for a new feature named IkvmReferences. Which allow you to insert a tag within your MSBuild files to automatically have IKVM convert your JAR files to assemblies.

Additionally, IKVM.Maven.Sdk allows you to directly reference Maven artifacts from your .NET projects.

Comment: Impressive! I've already came up with a different solution - But I will probably rethink it. Some questions are still left. Is it possible to include and manage multiple versions of the same dependency? Although how can I convert  a JAR, which depends on other JARS, to an asssembly? Does this happen automatically aswell or do I have to reference that anywhere?

Comment: Well, if you use IKVM to convert a JAR file to an assembly, the resulting assembly plays by all the normal rules of .NET assemblies. It is loaded into an AppDomain or AssemblyLoadContext. It binds to types of dependent assemblies using standard .NET methods. Everything after that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The JAR Files which is to be converted to DLL should be complied with JAVA JDK 1.7 or below. This limitation is because IKVM currently does not support converting JAR files compiled with JDK 1.8 or above.

https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/convert-jar-file-to-dll-for-use-in-visual-studio-projects/

Comment: IKVM supports JDK 1.8.